# Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova changes are not applying

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a cross platform mobile app with Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova.

However, I am having a strange issue that changes are not applying when I build and run the emulator (Ripple).

Does anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to open the DevTools with F12 and disable the cache.

**Open "settings":**

[image]

**... and disable cache:**

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: This didn't fix the problem but I marked as answered. Thank you for the response. That is a good tip actually.

Comment: Thanks Mirrh. Try to Clear the Cordova Cache in Visual Studio at Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova. You have to reopen the project after that Another hint: Try to avoid a second instance of Visual Studio with an active cordova project, this creates also some strange side effects.